# set a variable content one byte at a time

Tags: c++

I'm reading a message one byte (char) at a time and I would like to set the value of a variable based on that.
Is there a way to concatenate the bytes an then use a cast to set the value?

Something like:

```
mytype packet = (mytype) byteconcat;
```

If I'm rigth strings have an extra byte so that would be an issue.

Or alternatively can I create the variable and set the bytes as I receive them?

Comment: It all depend on the type of your variable

Comment: Are you familir with pointer arithmetics? You can copy bytes as a string and cast them to any type you want. Though this is not a problem-free thing. You're better off using a serializer, such as google protocol buffers or boost::serializer.

Comment: Yes you can, if You are got some expireience with pointers it won't be a problem. Coz void pointers can be cast to anything. 
And here's nice blogpost about this :
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/cpp-convert-datatypes/

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist can you be  more specific about the string solution? You also gave me an idea...if I create an array and then pass the address of the first element to a "mytype" pointer woul it work? (although it's ugly)

Comment: @user2833876 It would work, but under complicated conditions that you can't guarantee generally. First, it has to be contiguous in memory (this is easy); second, the computer that created the array should have the same endianness as the computer reinterpreting the bytes. Otherwise, there's no reason why it won't work. Again, consider using some serializer and it'll do this safely for you. You'll send a serialized object, and then deserialize it, and done! It's quite crazy to do it by hand in 2017 unless you're transferring ASCII strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union for that.

Let's assume you're sending integers over the net, catching them byte by byte on the other side.

Your union could look like this:

```
union Data {
   unsigned char bytes[4];
   int val;
}
```

and the code like this:

```
bool read(Data& outBuff, int& offset, unsigned char receivedByte)
{
   outBuff.bytes[offset++]= receivedByte;

   bool readyToRead = offset >= 4;
   if(readyToRead) {offset=0;}

   return readyToRead;
}
```